# Cannot install matplotlib because 'six' is a distutils

Tags: python, bash, unix, matplotlib

I want to install `matplotlib` on my new mac but am unable to because `six` is a "distutils installed project", what does this mean? I typed the following:

```
sudo -H python -m pip install -U matplotlib
```

which first throws all the usual jargon of "caching this; downloading that" And then, BOOM there it is; the error:

```
Cannot uninstall 'six'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to understand the error you have here, you'll need to understand what distutils are; They, in short, are ways to distribute and install Python extensions and packages. You can learn more about them [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Distutils). `six` is a way to wrap differences between Python 2 and 3.

That being said you can simply add `--ignore-installed` to your parameters like the following.

```
sudo -H python -m pip install -U matplotlib --ignore-installed
```